# BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams - unable to get any responses with "hello" after "node app.js"

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm working with this sample project and I'm totally new at this and have spent 3 days with virtually no documentation provided: https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams/tree/master/Node/samples
Our company would like to proactively message users in Teams so I thought this would be a good starting point.

***Step 1***: I ran npm install which installed `"botbuilder": "^3.16.0"`

***Step 2***: I did `npm install botbuilder-teams --save` in both /Node where the package.json is and also in /Node/samples -> I copied over the package.json here since I wasn't sure where exactly that npm module needed to be installed from
so again I have `Node/package.json` and `Node/samples/package.json` both isntalling the same sets of modules.

***Step 3***: from `cd Node/samples` and `node app.js`
From a browser I go to: `http://localhost:3978/` and get `{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"/ does not exist"}`

From the emulator, I go to `http://localhost:3978/` and type in `hello` and don't get any responses

[image]
[image]

I suspect that this is where my issue is:

```
// Put your registered bot here, to register bot, go to bot framework
var appName = 'app name';
var appId = 'app id';
var appPassword = 'app password';
var userId = 'user id';
var tenantId = 'tenant id';
```

> where do I get the **password**, is it the same as the **secrets** in
>   the azure portal?

I wanna run this ***locally so NOT deployed on Azure***
I'm using `ngrok` as you can see on the terminal pic attached to host the app locally for now.

When you go to `https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new` and create your bot, there's no where to set the `password` the legacy UI used to show this from videos I saw on youtube.

> Why am I not getting ANY responses?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the codes you provided, you should use this URL to test this sample on local:

```
http://localhost:3978/api/v1/bot/messages
```

[image]

[image]

You can create an app password in your Azure AD :
[image]

[image]

If you are just get started with nodejs bot , [this guide](https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-samples-hello-world-nodejs) will be better and detailed.

Comment: Thanks so much Stanley; the password is the client secret vaule; UserId => Object Id in bot framework UI

Comment: Welcome ! Hope you have a nice day !